# PostgreSQL doesn't take into account a DELETE in WITH before the request has ended

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have two tables to handle attachments:

- "files" which contains an `id` and other info
- "attachments" which contains the `id_file` (the `id` in the table `files` is the foreign key) and other info of the attachments.

Two tables to be able to share a file without duplicating it on the server (for your information).

When I delete an attachment, I want to delete the file only if there is no attachement left referring to its `id`.

I have this request, to delete all the attachments linked to a particular item (the 26th item of the table `TABLE_NAME`:

```
WITH deleted_files AS (
  DELETE FROM public.attachments a
  WHERE a.id_in_table = 26
    AND a.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
  RETURNING id_file
)
DELETE FROM public.files f
WHERE f.id IN (SELECT id FROM deleted_files)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM public.attachments a
    WHERE a.id_file = f.id
);
```

The problem is:

- the attachments are deleted correctly, but not the files
- if I run the same request again nothing is deleted (this is normal)
- if I run the second `DELETE` with the `ids` returned by the first delete, they are correctly deleted.

Is there some mechanism that keeps a shallow copy of the table with the deleted items, thus making the deletion of items impossible?

Comment: From the [Data modifying statements in WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) docs: `The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) says,

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that `RETURNING` data is the only way to communicate changes between different `WITH` sub-statements and the main query.

My advice is to run two separate `DELETE` statements. If you need them to share the same snapshot, run them in a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction. If the reason for using a single statement was a constraint, you can use a deferred constraint instead. Use a temporary table for the rows deleted by the first statement.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I never had the problem with INSERT ou UPDATE statements, that is strange. But if I remove the "NOT EXISTS" clause I don't get the result I expect.

Comment: You are right. I have modified my answer.